# Fastest way to perform calculations from two pandas dataframes with the same indexes and columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, each with the same indexes and columns. I'd like to create a third pandas dataframe containing the product of each cell of the other two.

Here is my current solution, but it is painfully slow.

```
import pandas as pd

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index, data=[])

for col, values in new_df.iteritems():
    for idx, value in values.iteritems():
        foo = df1.loc[idx][col]
        bar = df2.loc[idx][col]

        new_df.set_value(idx, col, foo * abs(bar))
```

Any better ways to do this that will be quicker? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe just df1*df2?

Comment: Exactly - did you try in your case `df1 * abs(df2)`?

Comment: @WeNYoBen why did I not try that.... wow. Feel free to add the answer and I'll select it.

Comment: @Adam hah , cause it is Friday afternoon , we do need a weekends :-) happy coding :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiply two pandas DataFrames based on column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685093/multiply-two-pandas-dataframes-based-on-column)

Comment: @Adam I am working on a answer contain more detail , one sec. :-)

Comment: @WeNYoBen regarding your Friday-theory - the duplicate happened on a Monday evening (_now hear those sharply screaming suspense violin sounds..._), so we're never safe. Never...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in above comments , you can do `DataFrame` mul with `DataFrame` , since `pandas` is `index` and `columns` sensitive , whenever it calculate the values , there are two hidden keys (`index` and `columns` ) only if both matched , it will calculated the value , if not , it will not calculated (return `NaN`)

In your case , you may like to add `reindex_like` as protection , so that you will not have any unwanted columns only exit in df2 .

```
df1.mul(df2.abs().reindex_like(df1),fill_value=0)
```